# How python can read the variables written in perl format?

Tags: perl, python-2.7, variables

Hi my python code needs to read variable file (written in perl format) and recognize the variables to use in python script. My variable file (variable.txt) is written as:

```
$x=1.2;
$y=90.2;
$z=4.2334;
$img1='version1.png';
$img2='version2.png';
```

I would like my python code to read above file and recognize the variables. I use below code to read the files

```
fp=open("variables.txt","r")
var=fp.read()
fp.close
print(var)
```

Above code will read all lines from variable.txt file but the python code did not recognize them as variables. What I mean is when I use those variables

```
 e.g. A=x+y
```

I would like to get A=91.4, but the error shows

> "name 'x' is not defined

Also when I tried to open image by

```
img1=Image.open("%s" %'img1') to open version1.png.
```

It did not work and shows

> No such file or directory: 'img1'

So, can anyone suggest how shall I command so that the variables in perl format to be read by python script? Tks

Comment: programming is not a magic. you are not even parsing perl file. use perl instead.

Comment: @YOU, I would like to but the whole code is written in python as some  parts of my code would be complicated if I use perl. I just need to read that variable file from my python script.

Comment: You said you have a Perl program (`variables.txt`), and you said you don't want to use Perl to execute it. That's not going to happen. You're going to have to define the format of the file must more stringently. Until then, this question isn't answerable.

Comment: I'd have the Perl program dump the variables in a JSON structure.

Comment: It may be possible to just remove the leading `$` and then just `eval` the result.  This is not a good solution for many reasons (you can google them), however, it would be better to follow the solution @ikegami suggests.

Comment: Well, for starters, that won't work if one of the lines is `$x = undef;` or even a simple dictionary (`$x = { k => "v" };`). Coming up with hacks is easy, but there's no way to evaluate which one might be appropriate

Comment: Agreed.  Just because it is possible (for some well defined input), doesn't mean its a good idea.

Comment: Thanks all for advice. It is not that i don't want to use perl. I do use perl as my main code, thats why the variable file is written in perl format (so that the main perl code will read and use those variables). But as part of main perl code, the sub-routine python code is executed (where that python code also has to use the same variable file). That's the reason I am trying to read perl format from python script. I will try to work out as you all suggested. Tks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest that you *don't* want to parse a variables file like this, and instead use a defined data transfer format.

Looking at your source data - JSON looks a good bet. To make this easy, insert it into a namespace such as a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my %export = ( x => 1.2,
               y => 90.2,
               z => 4.2334,
               img => [ 'version1.png', 'version2.png' ] ); 

print Dumper \%export;

open ( my $transfer, '>', 'transfer.json' ) or die $!; 
print {$transfer} to_json ( \%export, {pretty => 1});
close ( $transfer );
```

Which gives - in your file:

```
{
   "z" : 4.2334,
   "x" : 1.2,
   "img" : [
      "version1.png",
      "version2.png"
   ],
   "y" : 90.2
}
```

Which should be trivially readable in *any* language. (including Python).

Answer (score 0):

You can also shell out from Python to run the following Perl program, which will treat your *variables.txt* file as Perl code and wrap all the variables that are declared in it into a JSON object and print that.

```
perl -MJSON -e '
package Foo;
do "variable.txt";
package main;
my $export;
foreach my $key (keys %{Foo::}) {
    next if $key eq "BEGIN";
    $export->{$key} = ${"Foo::$key"};
}
print JSON::encode_json($export);'
```

So you would basically run this as a sub process or open it in Python, capture the output and JSON-decode it into a Python data structure.

The JSON output would look like this.

```
{
    'x': 1.2,
    'y': 90.2,
    'z': 4.2334,
    'img1': 'version1.png',
    'img2': 'version2.png'
}
```

This works by using [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) in a separate [`package`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) to include the variable definition file and treat it like Perl code (like PHP's `require`). A package is basically a namespace definition. It then switches back to the *main* package (that's the default in a Perl program) and read the symbol table of the other namespace. That contains all the variables we just read and defined.

Because they are not declared with `my`, they are treated as package variables rather than lexicals. Because there is no `use strict`, the program doesn't complain about that.

The symbol table might contain other stuff. When I tried this (without the `do`) it had a `BEGIN` block definition. Because I was lazy, I just parsed that one out explicitly. You could start looking at the reference types of those things in the symbol table, but I think it's not worth the effort. The *Foo* package shouldn't have anything else.

It then assigns them as keys into a hash reference, and afterwards converts that to JSON and outputs it.

---

I do believe that changing your data exchange format to JSON in general [as Sobrique suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37965251/1331451) is the better way to go.